# Run redux-thunk action without dispatch

Tags: redux, redux-thunk

I am using Redux to manage my app state, and I had an async action made with `redux-thunk`.

```
export const login = credentials => dispatch => {
   return doLogin(credentials).then(token => {
      localStorage.setItem('token', token)
      // this dispatch call was there before, but now it has gone,
      // because it is not necessary anymore
      // dispatch({ type: LOGIN_SUCCESS })
   })
}
```

The thing is that now I have an action which doesn't dispatch any actions into store, just does its job about login and storing token.

Is it okay to have such kind of action? I am not feel so confident about this code, but I don't know how to make it better.

Comment: Is this function not going to do anything at all with state?

Answer (score 4):

You're asking for an opinion on something that doesn't have hard rules, but the rule of thumb is that actions should be a minimal description of something that happened in the application.

Thunkified actions in general are a workaround for this behavior, but in this case it's okay to have this kind of action because even though it doesn't have an effect on Redux state through a reducer, you're using (thunk) middleware to perform side effects, and middleware is designed to respond to actions.

The fact that you're triggering an 'upstream' action that isn't consumed by a reducer downstream doesn't really matter, although it might be a good practice to still `dispatch({ type: 'LOGIN_REQUEST' })` at the start and `dispatch({ type: 'LOGIN_SUCCESS'})` at the end just so the downstream application has a way to know what is going on if it wants to do something about it later on.

Answer (score 4):

There is no rule for that and you don't necessarily need to dispatch any action, but it feels awkward that an action creator dispatches no action at all.

If you really don't need to dispatch any action, perhaps that component shouldn't be connected to Redux at all. An action creator **should** dispatch actions, if it doesn't, it's not an action creator, it's a function. You could create a simple component with a local function doing that, without bothering to add complexity with Redux.

But if you want to connect it to Redux, it can hardly make any sense to have an action creator that creates no actions. Dispatching actions is what an action creator was designed for.

Try thinking about user experience in this example you've presented in your question. You store your token in the local storage using an action creator or even better with a middleware, but you'll still need to dispatch some actions to let your application know what's going on so it can behave properly, letting your user know what's going on too. For example, I can clearly see room for 3 actions here:

- LOGIN_REQUEST: It'll set a state in the store to let the user know the application is trying to login, and disable the inputs so the application doesn't seem to behave crazily. Remember that in localhost the API responses might happen immediately but in a scenario with bad network or overloaded servers it'll take more time.
- LOGIN_SUCCESS: It'll let the application know that a token is now saved into local storage and that the user can be routed to its main page, or just change some elements of the current page to indicate a successful login.
- LOGIN_FAILURE: It'll let the user know that the credentials are invalid and ask him to try again.

Even if you don't route your user to another page after logging in, you might have to change something in the screen to let the user know that login has worked successfully and show an option for logging out. And dispatching actions to have a reducer handle the state mutation for your application is the Redux way to do that.

Answer (score 2):

It's matter of taste, but personally I wouldn't tightly couple your action creator with its effects (item set in local storage).

Instead, I'd dispatch an action, e.g. LOGIN_SUCCESS with token passed in as its data. Then have a middleware handling that action type - i.e. set the token in local storage.

This way you buy yourself more flexibility when it comes to how to handle credentials returned by doLogin. You should be pursuing this paradigm of each piece of software doing its own thing and doing it best. So you have a function to authenticate user that then hands over auth token to another piece that knows best how to handle it.

Comment: You're probably right about middleware. But localStorage is used only for that feature, so I thought that it would be overhead to add a middleware just for this case.

Comment: I guess so, but still - separated concerns are easier to reason about. All in all - it's a matter of choice.